# Static maps in Email

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am currently sending out a Google static maps link in an email as below. We currently send the API key with this also. With the changes being made around the APIs we wanted to restrict the usage of this e.g. by referrer like I have on our website. How can I go about doing this for email?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:%7C{LatLong1}&markers=color:green%7Clabel:%7C{LatLong2}&key={APIKey}
```

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way to protect Static Maps API calls by referrer in emails. You should apply a different approach. You can generate an API key exclusively for Static Maps calls and protect it by API in addition you can protect your calls using a digital signature. This is an alternative way of protection that you can use for Static Maps API.

> For the standard API, the recommended method of authentication is to include an API key and a digital signature in all requests to the Maps Static API. The API key is required. The digital signature is required if you enable pay-as-you-go billing. The unique signature allows our servers to verify that any site generating requests using your API key is authorized to do so.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#standard-auth

I would suggest trying this approach.